# Add daily_volume so far to dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

i have the following dataframe for a day, in which each row is a minute.:

```
stock,date,open,high,low,close,volume
AACG,202005010928,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,200
AACG,202005010929,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,100
AACG,202005010930,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,1250
AACG,202005010934,0.72,0.72,0.72,0.72,100
AACG,202005010937,0.71,0.71,0.68,0.68,3599
AACG,202005010938,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65,2200
AACG,202005010947,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,125
AACG,202005010955,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,300
AACG,202005011002,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,10818
AACG,202005011112,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,100
AACG,202005011125,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,1103
AACG,202005011153,0.7,0.7,0.66,0.66,3334
AACG,202005011223,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,100
AACG,202005011234,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,250
AACG,202005011258,0.71,0.71,0.71,0.71,100
AACG,202005011321,0.73,0.73,0.72,0.72,1200
AACG,202005011329,0.7,0.7,0.7,0.7,4200
AACG,202005011427,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,100
AACG,202005011432,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65,369
AACG,202005011529,0.66,0.66,0.66,0.66,254
AACG,202005011544,0.73,0.73,0.7,0.73,1397
AACG,202005011545,0.74,0.74,0.74,0.74,100
AACG,202005011548,0.73,0.73,0.73,0.73,100
AACG,202005011549,0.74,0.74,0.74,0.74,100
AAL,202005010900,11.29,11.3,11.29,11.29,8201
AAL,202005010901,11.28,11.31,11.26,11.28,26935
AAL,202005010902,11.3,11.34,11.3,11.33,31958
AAL,202005010903,11.33,11.36,11.31,11.35,44487
AAL,202005010904,11.35,11.35,11.32,11.33,22240
```

I want to use a vectorial method (not `iterrows` since it takes time) to add a column that computes daily volume so far, for each row. 
How can I do this?
Thank you

Comment: You are looking for [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) I guess, if you dataframe contains only one day, then `df['volume'].cumsum()` would do it

Answer (score 0):

```
df['cumsum'] = df['volume'].cumsum()
```

Comment: Code only answers, without explanation or supporting documentation are frowned upon. SO is a resource for knowledge & learning. Compete, self-contained answers that direct readers to reasoning when/why their solution addresses the OP's issue has more long term value, skews Q & A to highlight knowledge, rather than give-me-code coding service type questions, & helps future visitors apply your answer to their own issues. Finally, well thought out, complete Answers with explanations are much more likely to be upvoted, as they help visitors the most. Please consider editing to add long term value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new cumulative column by stock issue by day.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['stock', df['date'].dt.date])['volume'].cumsum()

df
    stock   date    open    high    low close   volume  cumsum
0   AACG    2020-05-01 09:28:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    200 200
1   AACG    2020-05-01 09:29:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    100 300
2   AACG    2020-05-01 09:30:00 0.80    0.80    0.80    0.80    1250    1550
3   AACG    2020-05-01 09:34:00 0.72    0.72    0.72    0.72    100 1650
4   AACG    2020-05-01 09:37:00 0.71    0.71    0.68    0.68    3599    5249
5   AACG    2020-05-01 09:38:00 0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    2200    7449
6   AACG    2020-05-01 09:47:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    125 7574
7   AACG    2020-05-01 09:55:00 0.71    0.71    0.71    0.71    300 7874
8   AACG    2020-05-01 10:02:00 0.70    0.70    0.70    0.70    10818   18692
9   AACG    2020-05-01 11:12:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    100 18792
10  AACG    2020-05-01 11:25:00 0.70    0.70    0.70    0.70    1103    19895
11  AACG    2020-05-01 11:53:00 0.70    0.70    0.66    0.66    3334    23229
12  AACG    2020-05-01 12:23:00 0.70    0.70    0.70    0.70    100 23329
13  AACG    2020-05-01 12:34:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    250 23579
14  AACG    2020-05-01 12:58:00 0.71    0.71    0.71    0.71    100 23679
15  AACG    2020-05-01 13:21:00 0.73    0.73    0.72    0.72    1200    24879
16  AACG    2020-05-01 13:29:00 0.70    0.70    0.70    0.70    4200    29079
17  AACG    2020-05-01 14:27:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    100 29179
18  AACG    2020-05-01 14:32:00 0.65    0.65    0.65    0.65    369 29548
19  AACG    2020-05-01 15:29:00 0.66    0.66    0.66    0.66    254 29802
20  AACG    2020-05-01 15:44:00 0.73    0.73    0.70    0.73    1397    31199
21  AACG    2020-05-01 15:45:00 0.74    0.74    0.74    0.74    100 31299
22  AACG    2020-05-01 15:48:00 0.73    0.73    0.73    0.73    100 31399
23  AACG    2020-05-01 15:49:00 0.74    0.74    0.74    0.74    100 31499
24  AAL 2020-05-01 09:00:00 11.29   11.30   11.29   11.29   8201    8201
25  AAL 2020-05-01 09:01:00 11.28   11.31   11.26   11.28   26935   35136
26  AAL 2020-05-01 09:02:00 11.30   11.34   11.30   11.33   31958   67094
27  AAL 2020-05-01 09:03:00 11.33   11.36   11.31   11.35   44487   111581
28  AAL 2020-05-01 09:04:00 11.35   11.35   11.32   11.33   22240   133821
```